# Does msync performance depend on the size of the provided range?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, mmap

I'm making many small random writes to a mmaped file. I want to ensure consistency, so from time to time I use `msync`, but I don't want to keep track of every single small write that I made. In the current Linux kernel implementation, is there a performance penalty for using `msync` on the whole file? For example if the file is 100GB, but I only made total of 10MB changes? Is the kernel looping over every page in the range provided for `msync` to find the dirty pages to flush or are those kept on some sort of linked list/other structure?

Comment: I've reworded the title of your question to make it clearer, let me know if there is any issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: no it doesn't, kernel structures that hold the needed information are designed to make the operation efficient regardless of range size.

Pages of mappable objects are kept in a [radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), however the Linux kernel implementation of radix trees has an additional special feature: entries can be marked with up to 3 different marks, and marked entries can be found and iterated on a lot faster. The actual data structure used is called "XArray", you can find more information about it in [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/745073/) or in [`Documentation/core-api/xarray.rst`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.16/core-api/xarray.html).

Dirty pages have a special mark which can be set (`PAGECACHE_TAG_DIRTY`) allowing for them to be quickly found when writeback is needed (e.g. `msync`, `fsync`, etc). Furthermore, XArrays provide an O(1) mechanism to check whether any entry exists with a given mark, so in the case of pages it can be quickly determined whether a writeback is needed at all even before looking for dirty pages.

In conclusion, you should not incur in a noticeable performance penalty when calling `msync` on the entire mapping as opposed to only a smaller range of actually modified pages.